# How get max count with min key from list integer with linq written in one expression

Tags: c#, linq

For example I have following list

```
var arr = new List<int> { 1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3 };
```

I implemented as:

```
var res1 = from type in arr
   group type by type into ByrdTypes
   select new
   {
      Group = ByrdTypes.Key,
      Count = ByrdTypes.Count()
   }; 


var correct = from item in res1
   where item.Count == res1.Max(y => y.Count)
   select item;

var result = correct.Min(x => x.Group);
```

This is working solution. But how can I rewrite this in one Linq expression(query)? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` then `First` or `Last`

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3 };
var result = list
   .GroupBy(type => type)
   .Select(x => new {Group = x.Key, Count = x.Count()})
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
   .First();

// The above will get you the group with the highest count 

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
{ Group = 4, Count = 3 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the solution to the Hackerrank Migratory Birds challenge, this is my solution:

```
public static int MigratoryBirds(List<int> arr)
{
    var group = arr.GroupBy(a => a)
        .Select(grouping => new 
        { 
             Key = grouping.Key, 
             Count = grouping.Count() 
        })
        .OrderByDescending(arg => arg.Count)
        .ThenBy(arg => arg.Key)
        .First();

    return group.Key;
}
```